# How to call make in subdirectories in a certain order?

Tags: makefile

So my project directory structure looks like this:

```
root/
--logger/
--protos/
--backend/
```

Directory has a Makefile and the top-level Makefile in root calls all make in each subdirectory:

```
TOPTARGETS := all clean

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(TOPTARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)
```

The executable will be in the backend folder and my issue right now is that I want to make the object files in logger and protos before calling make in backend.

How do I enforce an order like this?

Comment: Try creating prerequisites, eg: add a line similar to `backend: logger protos`; also you might experiment with multiple jobs like `make -j4` to confirm needed ordering.

Comment: Your question is one of the top reasons why [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://www.real-linux.org.uk/recursivemake.pdf).